# How to close popup in Selenium using Java.?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, popupwindow, window-handles

I am unable to close popup (Find attached screenshot) in the website>> https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-playground

[image]

I tried closing the element by using locators but I got element not interactable error and also I tried with getWindow Handle method but no use. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on X button.
Here is the locator:
css -> #exit_popup_close

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the close button and click as follows.

```
WebElement alertBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='exit_popup_close']"));
alertBox.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code used for alert/pop

Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switch().to.alert().dismiss()

Try to use above one.

Comment: that is not a browser alert to use that command.